# how to set nicedit uneditable

Tags: javascript, nicedit

i'm using nicedit js which is is a WYSIWYG editor in my textarea to view html doc, but it still editable, how to set this nicedit to readonly mode, i try to search from its doc but unable to find it, do any one have experience using nicedit,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Here is a helpful jQuery solution that I use with nicEdit:

```
jQuery('.nicEdit-main').attr('contenteditable','false');
jQuery('.nicEdit-panel').hide();
```

You can simply change it back to 'true' to make it editable again.

Note: I would consider toggling the div background-color along with this solution.

Comment: To change the background-color use `jQuery('.nicEdit-main').attr('contenteditable','false').parent().css("background-color", "#EEEEEE")`

Comment: Make sure you put it inside the bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () { where nicEditor is instantiated

Answer (score 3):

finally the solution is

var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
myNicEditor.addInstance('templateContent');
nicEditors.findEditor("templateContent").disable();

Comment: I couldn't make it. Please guide me. I have textarea with name 'area3'. I converted it into niceedit. But even after i replace 'templateContent' in the above code with 'area3', i couldn't make it readonly. Please guide me.

Comment: hv u declare the above code inside bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { }

Comment: it kind of works because it is disabled but when clicking the textarea it gets enabled again :(

Answer (score 1):

With the statement 
`nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").disable();  niceditor` is non editable
But

```
nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").attr("contentEditable","true");
```

does not make it editable again

Comment: hmm ... the first part is a duplication of the self-answer, and the second is what?

Answer (score 1):

for me only this worked:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('nicEdit-main')[0].removeAttribute('contentEditable');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess it is a WYSIWYG editor.

Try this...

```
document.getElementById('nicedit').removeAttribute('contentEditable');
```

Answer (score 0):

function edit(){

a = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('area5',{hasPanel : true});
}

function no_edit(){

a.removeInstance('area5');
}

Answer (score 0):

**nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").disable()**;

above statement will disable the TextArea.

For enabling the TextArea, update the nicEdit.js (see below what to update)

search for **disable: function () { this.elm.setAttribute("contentEditable", "false"); }**

next to this code add the below code

**, enable: function () { this.elm.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true"); }**

and in your JavaScript call **nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").enable();**